# Adding irrelevant images to an answer is acceptable?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, edits, declined-flags

A few days ago, I came across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450593/how-to-clear-the-content-of-a-div-using-javascript/3450609#3450609) which has totally irrelevant images.

Is this allowed in Stack Overflow?

I raised a flag to the moderators but I received a reply as **declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That post *is* over two years old, but no, that is not appropriate for an answer. Not only do the images provide absolutely nothing to the context of the answer, but ***GIF animation***!? Please no...

Comment: i raised a flag to the moderators but i received a reply as **declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention**

Comment: @krish: You shouldn't use a moderator flag for this. Simply edit it out yourself. If you don't have the reputation to edit, I'm positive other users would approve the suggestion.

Comment: @animuson: thanks for clear the point about flagging.

Comment: Please note that it's perfectly fine to flag problematic stuff on _locked_ posts, or where no means at all exist for you to do something about it yourself. Just explain that in the flag ('other' is always the way to go to inform of us exceptional circumstances).

Comment: @TimPost : yes i use the other option and wrote as "unwanted images are added"

Comment: @krish The reason you gave is _extremely_ vague and confusing. Next time try "Post contains animated images that don't add anything but laughs and slow down my screen" Or something like that. Always try to be as specific as possible. From the reason you gave, the mod might have thought you were saying the images were offensive, which they weren't.

Answer (score 4):

The reason that the flag was declined was not because the images were okay or acceptable, but because regular users of the Stack Overflow community are empowered to handle a lot of basic, janitorial moderation tasks.

Even as a user with less than 500 reputation, you can suggest an edit by removing the images. Not only would you gain 2 reputation points once your edit is accepted, but it also frees up the moderators to stay focused on handling the exceptional cases that the community is unable to resolve.

This takes some getting used to, as Stack Exchange sites are not like traditional forums. You have the power. [Insert animated GIF of HE-MAN here].

See the [Stack Overflow Privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges) for a list of the various reputation thresholds and the tasks that you can perform at each level. Good luck!